# custom directive within ng-template does not work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, modal-dialog, angular-ui

I am using script tag with ng-template for displaying my form in modal dialog.
I am using angular ui $modal service here.

My issue is, when I pass templateUrl argument to $modal service with my ng-template, my custom directive within ng-template is not processed by angular

see

http://plnkr.co/edit/enPgDg6QnNPv1e7Z2T2X?p=preview

where my custom directive `<myDirective></myDirective>` is not being rendered on modal dialog.

any quick help will be appreciated

Comment: On the plunkr you have wrote tyemplate

Comment: yes, fixed the typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/Zvhu4OMDqpHFOgTCg5bU?p=preview

If name of your directive is '`myDirective`'  in HTML you should use `<my-directive>`

Read more here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive